# Gnome Single display shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display

I'm using ubuntu 21.10 and Gnome 40.4.0 and I need a shortcut to change my second monitor to standby mode. When I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it shows me:

[image: Screenshot 1]

1. Mirror
2. Join Displays
3. External Only
4. Built-in Only

Windows got a nice option when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> I can only use the first monitor:

[image: Screenshot 2]

For doing this in gnome I have to go Settings → Displays → Single Display:

[image: Screenshot 3]

I'll be glad if you show me a shortcut for this option.

Comment: Where did you learn about that shortcut `Super + P`? I can't even find that. I think it should be hidden somewhere in `dconf` settings or in `gsettings`. Probably you can find what you want near that, or write a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

Hit  <kbd>Super</kbd>  +  <kbd>P</kbd>  and choose Built-in Only.

---

Here are the GNOME equivalents of the options in Windows.

```
PC Screen Only (Windows) -> Built-in Only (GNOME)
Duplicate -> Mirror
Extend -> Join Displays
Second Screen Only -> External Only
```

Comment: Neither Built-in Only nor External Only will make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that the only options that work are "Join Displays" and "Mirror. "Built-in only" and "External only" don't change anything. for doing what I want I have to go to settings.